# System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'

Tags: c#, winforms, impersonation

I'm trying to run my winform app with a local window user credential, for this I'm using below class for `impersonation`,

```
public class Impersonation
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Impersonate given logon information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="logon">Windows logon name.</param>
    /// <param name="password">password</param>
    /// <param name="domain">domain name</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Impersonate(string logon, string password, string domain)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (LogonUser(logon, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
        LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
        {

            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
            {
                tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                if (null != impersonationContext) return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Unimpersonate.
    /// </summary>
    public static void UnImpersonate()
    {
        impersonationContext.Undo();
    }

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int LogonUser(
    string lpszUserName,
    String lpszDomain,
    String lpszPassword,
    int dwLogonType,
    int dwLogonProvider,
    ref IntPtr phToken);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public extern static int DuplicateToken(
    IntPtr hToken,
    int impersonationLevel,
    ref IntPtr hNewToken);

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT = 4;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;
}
```

Now here is the code for 'winform` startup code,

```
static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            string userName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter User Name", "User Name");
            string password = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter Password", "Password");

            if (!Impersonation.Impersonate(userName, password, Environment.MachineName))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login failed.");
                return;
            }

            Application.Run(new Form1());

            Impersonation.UnImpersonate();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I'm passing the credential for local window user, login is successful and while loading the `form`, I'm getting error,

> System.Security.SecurityException: 'Requested registry access is not allowed.'

and here is the full stack trace,

> at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowSecurityException(ExceptionResource resource)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name, Boolean writable)
>      at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.OpenSubKey(String name)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.LinkUtilities.GetIEColor(String name)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.LinkUtilities.get_IELinkColor()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.get_LinkColor()
>      at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16 layer)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel.WndProc(Message& msg)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>      at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to access the registry hive of another user, i think you'll find you will need the to be an administrator or LocalSystem account.

You can find a snippet of information at the bottom of the [LoadUserProfileA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-loaduserprofilea) *Win32 Api*

> Starting with Windows XP Service Pack 2 (SP2) and Windows Server 2003,
>   the caller must be an administrator or the LocalSystem account. **It is
>   not sufficient for the caller to merely impersonate the administrator
>   or LocalSystem account.**

***Note*** : (This is speculative) however, you could possibly launch a new process (under the admin credentials) to load the profile and access the registry.

Comment: A workaround is to get the ownership of the key, change permissions for the user you impersonate and then set the ownership back to the SID of old owner. HOWEVER, this is not advised as the user now have permisions he shouldn't have into its hands.